# Правильно сформировать json и правильно прочитать в андроиде

Tags: android, php, java, json, mysql

делаю все по [мануалу](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database) , но у меня дроид не парсит json-ответ. вот результат выполнения пхп скрипта

```
[{"id":"1","machine":"\u0421\u0402\u0420\u0455\u0421\u201a\u0420\u0455\u0420\u0458\u0420\u00b0\u0420\u0405 55","time_begin":"1053585"},{"id":"2","machine":"\u0420\u0457\u0420\u0455\u0420\u0456 98","time_begin":"12365"}]
```

вот сам пхп скрипт

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","ххх","ххх");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_select_db("testandr");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from graph");    
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
echo json_safe_encode($output);
mysql_close();
?>
```

а вот сам парсинг

```
        //parse json data
        try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                       JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        id = json_data.getInt("id");
                        machine = json_data.getString("machine");
                        time_begin = json_data.getInt("time_begin");
                        //time_finish = json_data.getInt("time_finish");                            
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), machine , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Итак, воспроизвел ваш код парсинга JSON'а. Вот мой вариант, он ничем в принципе не отличается от вашего

```
public void onParseIt(View source) {
    String sourceJson = "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"machine\":\"Nissan\",\"time_begin\":\"1053585\"},                              {\"id\":\"2\",\"machine\":\"Toyota\",\"time_begin\":\"12365\"}]";
    try {
        final JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(sourceJson);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            final JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = obj.getInt("id");
            String machine = obj.getString("machine");
            int timeBegin = obj.getInt("time_begin");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Machine: " + machine,    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException jsonEx) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + jsonEx.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Все парсится и отображается корректно.
Могу предположить вариант, когда ваш пы-хы-пы скрипт выдает андроиду не всегда корректный JSON. Проверьте его.
Еще я бы посоветовал перед тем, как брать какое-то поле у JSONObject'а проверять наличие сего поля в нем

```
if (json.has("name")) {
    mName = json.getString("name");
}
```

Это немного увеличит объем кода, который нужно будет напидалить руками.
Совет номер два: посмотрите в сторону [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) или другой аналогичной библиотеки для работы с JSON'ом, это позволит в разы сократить написание повторяющегося кода для JSON-парсинга. Строить POJO-класс (пусть будет модель) и аннотациями указываете соответствие ее членов полям в JSON-объекте

Comment: почему тогда у меня постоянно парсинг вылетает в catch?((
вот тут получаю ответ http://www.bg13.nx0.ru/city.php
и еще вопрос. почему у вас JSON строка со слэшами идет?

Comment: Со слешами строка идет потому что я заэкранировал символы кавычки, это нужно, чтобы json-строка была валидной Java-строкой

Comment: Покажите что конкретно выводится в лог в catch-блоке. Еще было бы неплохо взглянуть на весть stacktrace

Comment: Попробуйте на всякий случай при формировании JSON-ответа убрать обрамление кавычками int-овых значений. Хотя у меня и так и так корректно парсится.
Может у вас вообще ошибка не в json-парсинге?

Comment: ошибка кажись в пхп, если ручками проэкранировать все кавычки, то всё парсится нормально... не пойму почему пхп не экранирует их, со стороны пхп str_replace не работает, не подменяет " на \", со стороны java тоже не подменяются ковычки реплейсом...

Comment: Не нужно в java ничего риплейсить, добейтесь корректной генерации json-ответов и все у вас получится!

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value ﻿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray вот что пишет

Comment: это не может быть изза кодировки на стороне мускула? какую кодировку надо ставить? сейчас стоит utf-8